# How can I create Automapper with different models

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have two models that I want to map automatically, using the automapper.

Model A with properties

```
public string field1 {get; set;}
public string field2 {get; set;}
```

Model B with the properties

```
public string field1 {get; set;}
public string field2 {get; set;}
public string field3 {get; set;}
```

AND

```
CreateMap<ModelA, ModelB>()
          .ForMember (d => d.field1, o => o.MapFrom (s => s.field1))
          .ForMember (d => d.field2, o => o.MapFrom (s => s.field2))
          .ForAllOtherMembers (opts => opts.Ignore ());
```

But I get this error:

> Unmapped properties: field3

FrontEnd Controller call:

```
ModelB oModelB = mapper.Map<ModelA,ModelB>(pModelA);
```

Comment: Could you perhaps share your code where you do the actual mapping? Something like - ModelB modelB  = Mapper.Map<ModelB>(modelA);

Comment: Sure: 
ModelB oModelB = mapper.Map<ModelA, ModelB>(pModelA);

Comment: It works for me, I'm running version 7.0.1 though, which I think ignores unmapped properties

Comment: @JanusPienaar No, no AM version does that, except the occasional bug.

Comment: @VascoSilva I don't see it either. A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Thanks for confirming. The only way I can reproduce this is to remove the .ForAllOtherMembers (opts => opts.Ignore ()); call and add Mapper.Configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid(); We'll need to see the complete code to give an answer